# How to connect between two close unconnected points in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a binary image that looks like this:
[image]

I sometimes receive an unclosed concave just as in the above example.
I want to close all the concaves in such examples but I just can't figure out how.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet might be to do what's called morphological closing on your image above.  You can take a gander at this wiki page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_%28morphology%29)

You can do this on your own using the `imdilate` and `imerode` functions.

The other option is to use `bwmorph`: `bwmorph(img, 'close')`

NOTE: `bwmorph` requires that you provide a binary image to it (`img`) above.

I prefer using `imdilate` and `imerode` as you can specify your own structuring element (the matrix that is used to determine what should be filled in).  `bwmorph`, if I recall correctly uses a `one(3)` structering element to do its operations.